# Can't get RubaXa/angular-legacy-sortablejs to move items between lists

Tags: angularjs, rubaxa-sortable

Can someone tell me why [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/LsIeBGdFKfQGRZqLcpwb?p=preview) will not allow me to move items between the two lists?

I am able to get shared lists to work using the plain RubaXa Sortable library and plain Javascript, but I have not been able to get them to work with Angular and RubaXa/angular-legacy-sortablejs library.

I have read and re-read the docs on the configuration options [here](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options) and I swear I am doing it correctly.

I have also reviewed the example from the docs (not allowed to link it here due to low rep points) with no success.

I have created two lists and connected them using identical config info:

```
var ctrl = this;
ctrl.sortableConf = {
    group: {
        name: 'tags',
        pull: true,
        put: true
    },
    sort: true,
    animation: 150,
    draggable: '.list-group-item',
    filter: '.js-remove',
    chosenClass: ".sortable-chosen" 
};
```

They both sort just fine internally, I just can't drag an item from one to the other or vice versa.

Comment: I'm going out here on a limb, but i suppose its because the lists are using 2 totally different controllers

Comment: It's a good guess, but no. They need separate controllers, but the they are supposed to be joined by the group element in the config. I think that is where the problem is, but I can;t seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-legacy-sortablejs) is wrong, or I don't know how to properly reference it when not using a partial page instead of an embedded template.

After debugging the options-loading code in sortable.js, I realized that it was not loading the `group:` block from the `ctrl.sortableConf` and I was getting stuck with the default values:

## [image: group object while debugging sortable.js]

After trying a ton of different ways to do this, I stumbled on [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-legacy-sortablejs) and was able to work it out form there.

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEcPQ36TUQJ0BwDlaZPC?p=preview) and a copy of the code just in case that goes away:

```
    // create angular app
    var tagsApp = angular.module('tagsApp', ['ng-sortable']);

    tagsApp.controller('bugTagController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.tags = [
        'Beans',
        'Potatoes'
      ];

      $scope.bugTagControllerConfig = {
        group: 'tags',
        pull: true,
        put: true,
        sort: true,
        animation: 150,
        draggable: '.list-group-item',
        filter: '.js-remove',
        chosenClass: ".sortable-chosen",
        accept: function(sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {
          console.log('masterTagController:accept');
          return true;
        },
        onStart: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onStart');
        },
        onEnd: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onEnd');
        },
        onAdd: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onAdd');
        },
        onRemove: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onAdd');
        },

        onFilter: function(evt) {
          var el = masterTags.closest(evt.item); // get dragged item
          el && el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
          console.log('masterTagController:onFilter');
        },
        onSort: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onSort');
          var $item = $(evt.item);
          var id = $item.data('id');
          if (evt.action === 'add') {
            console.log('masterTagController:add');
            // put a check to make sure it's unique
            // check to see if this node has already been added  and prevent it it has
            var itemCount = evt.item.parentNode.children.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
              var $child = $(evt.item.parentNode.children[i]);
              var childId = $child.data('id');

              if (childId === id && i !== evt.newIndex) {
                console.log('masterTagController:rejectedNewItem');
                evt.preventDefault();
                return;
              }
            }

            if (evt.newIndex === itemCount - 1) {
              Sortable.utils.swap(evt.item.parentNode, evt.newIndex, evt.newIndex - 1);
            }
          }
        }

      };
    }]);

    tagsApp.controller('masterTagController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.tags = [
        'Apples',
        'Oranges',
        'Comquats',
        'Bannanas',
        'Pineapples'
      ];

      $scope.masterTagControllerConfig = {
        group: 'tags',
        pull: true,
        put: true,
        sort: true,
        animation: 150,
        draggable: '.list-group-item',
        filter: '.js-remove',
        chosenClass: ".sortable-chosen",
        accept: function(sourceItemHandleScope, destSortableScope) {
          console.log('masterTagController:accept');
          return true
        },
        onStart: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onStart');
        },
        onEnd: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onEnd');
        },
        onAdd: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onAdd');
        },
        onRemove: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onAdd');
        },

        onFilter: function(evt) {
          var el = masterTags.closest(evt.item); // get dragged item
          el && el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
          console.log('masterTagController:onFilter');
        },
        onSort: function(evt) {
          console.log('masterTagController:onSort');
          var $item = $(evt.item);
          var id = $item.data('id');
          if (evt.action === 'add') {
            console.log('masterTagController:add');
            // put a check to make sure it's unique
            // check to see if this node has already been added  and prevent it it has
            var itemCount = evt.item.parentNode.children.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
              var $child = $(evt.item.parentNode.children[i]);
              var childId = $child.data('id');

              if (childId === id && i !== evt.newIndex) {
                console.log('masterTagController:rejectedNewItem');
                evt.preventDefault();
                return;
              }
            }

            if (evt.newIndex === itemCount - 1) {
              Sortable.utils.swap(evt.item.parentNode, evt.newIndex, evt.newIndex - 1);
            }
          }
        }

      };
    }]);
```

And here is the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div ng-app="tagsApp">
        <!-- Starting Secondary Tags -->
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h2>Tags on this list</h2>
          <div class="well" ng-controller="bugTagController">
            <ul id="bugTags" class="list-group" ng-sortable="bugTagControllerConfig" ng-model="tags" style="well-lg">
              <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-sortable-item style="well-lg">
                <div ng-sortable-item-handle>{{ tag }}</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Ending Secondary Tags -->

        <!-- Starting Master Tags -->
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <h2>Master Tag List</h2>
          <div class="well" ng-controller="masterTagController">
            <ul id="masterTags" class="list-group" ng-sortable="masterTagControllerConfig" ng-model="tags" style="well-lg">
              <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-sortable-item style="well-lg">
                <div ng-sortable-item-handle>{{ tag }}</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- Ending Master Tags -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js" integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="ng-sortable.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```